# return partialview after httppost asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-modal, partial-views

I am creating a web app in `asp.net mvc`

I have a partial view to reset password which opens inside bootstrap modal,

now on `HttpPost` I have a if condition which looks like below

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.NewPassword))
{
    TempData["PMessage"] = CustomHelper.Translate("Please Enter new Password");
    return PartialView(model);
}
```

but my main url is changing to this partial view like below

http://localhost:8080/User/ResetPassword

here `ResetPassword` is my partialview name

my partialView looks like below

```
@(Html.BeginForm("ResetPassword", "User", FormMethod.Post))
{
<div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <!-- Modal data-->
</div>
}
```

my full post method

```
[HttpPost]

public ActionResult ResetPassword(ResetPasswordModel model)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.NewPassword))
    {
        TempData["PMessage"] = "Please Enter new Password";
        return PartialView(model);
    }
    //if success
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

how can I prevent this, I just want to load modal and not whole page,

what can be the fixes here?

or Should I go for client side validation?

Page flow in detail

this is how my page looks

[image: My page]

if the user clicks on reset password, the below bootstrap modal appears

[image: My modal]

without entering any data if user clicks on OK, post method has been called and  the page is being redirected to resetpassword.cshtml as I am returning like below

```
return PartialView(model);
```

what I need to do if I only want to refresh modal/partial view on validation on controller

Comment: updated again..

Comment: updated my question hope, it help you to understand what I am trying to do

Comment: I think you should prevent submitting you reset form. You can collect the form data and post in using AJAX request. After the request is completed you can either refresh the modal using your partial view content or redirect to the index page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making normal HTTP request it's used to handle regular browser calls (like form submits) and return full HTML pages to client.

In your case you have to make ajax request to handle ResetPassword post method to avoid redirect.

```
<!-- modal placeholder-->
<div id='myModal' class='modal fade in'>
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div id='myModalContent'></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

this url return your reset form and load it into a modalcontent

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Reset", "Account", new { class = "resetpassword" })" ></a>


$(function () {
            $(document).on("click", "a.resetpassword", function (e) {
                $('#myModalContent').load(this.href, function () {
                    $('#myModal').modal({
                        /*backdrop: 'static',*/
                        keyboard: true
                    }, 'show');
                    bindForm(this);
                });
                return false;
            });
        });

        function bindForm(dialog) {
            $('form', dialog).submit(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                if ($('#resetFormId').valid()) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: this.action,
                        type: this.method,
                        data: $(this).serialize(),
                        success: function (result) {
                            if (result.success) {
                                $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                            } else {
                                $('#myModalContent').html(result);
                                bindForm(dialog);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
                return false;
            });
        }
```